# NO2 CSV downloaded files shows zero values for consider date range using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I am downloading the CSV file, the results show zeros in the CSV file. How can I download exact NO2 values as shown in Chart after running the mentioned below code in Google Earth Engine?

```
// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var BergamoGeometry = ee.FeatureCollection(BergamoGeometry);
print(BergamoGeometry);
Map.centerObject(BergamoGeometry);
Map.addLayer(BergamoGeometry);
//////////////////////////////////////

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2")
                 .filterBounds(BergamoGeometry)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-03-30', '2019-04-29'));
                 
var NO2 = dataset.select('NO2_column_number_density');
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.0002,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
// Create and print the chart.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(NO2, BergamoGeometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm that's a bit unfortunate behaviour. Seems like to option to download the chart has difficulty with small numbers. You could simply multiply the image values by e.g. 10000:

```
var NO2 = dataset.select('NO2_column_number_density')
              .map(function(image){
                return image.multiply(10000)
                // copy the image properties to the new image
                .set(image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()))
              })
```

Or code the similar function as the `ui.Chart.image.series` and download that directly as CSV:

```
NO2 = NO2.map(function(image){
  return image.set(image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), BergamoGeometry, 30));
});

Export.table.toDrive({collection: NO2, 
                      description: 'NO2means',
                      selectors: ['system:time_start', 'NO2_column_number_density']
})
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6ed393068b357122d4fa9fc84bd589db)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.